# Continue acting weird?

Tags: c, operating-system, signals

Iv'e encountered this code:

```
int main() {
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    int pid;

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        sysCallFailureProcedure();
    }

    if (pid == SON_PROCESS) {

        dup2(fd[0], 0);
        execlp(TETRIS_DISP_NAME, TETRIS_DISP_NAME, NULL);

        sysCallFailureProcedure();
    }

    char c;
    enum Bool hasNotQuitted;
    while (hasNotQuitted) {
        c = getch();
        if (!isAlegalKey(c)) {
            continue;
        }
        if(write(fd[1], &c, 1) < 0) {
            sysCallFailureProcedure();
        }
        kill(pid, SIGUSR2);

        if (c == QUIT_KEY) {
            hasNotQuitted = false;
        }
    }

    return OPERATION_SUCCEEDED;
}
```

I'm trying to improve it and lose the continue statement (its a bad practice). But when I do,
it causes my program to function not propetly, its a runner program for some kind of a tetris game. All I did is to replace the continue with this:

```
if(write(fd[1], &c, 1) < 0) {
    sysCallFailureProcedure();
}
kill(pid, SIGUSR2);

if (c == QUIT_KEY) {
    hasNotQuitted = false;
}
```

meaning the code that follows the continue.
Can anyone tell me what did I miss?

Comment: who told you `continue` was bad practice? It's a tool in the toolbox just like the other features of the language.

Comment: You don't initialize `hasNotQuitted` before you first test it, so you've no idea whether your loop will exit or not.

Comment: You could remove it if you wanted and just put the rest of the loop in an `else{...}`? I think this is more readable though

Comment: `enum Bool hasNotQuitted;` - this is a bad practice indeed. You have a standard `bool` type.

Comment: but to answer your question, you need to change the logic of your `if` statement. All the stuff after the `continue` is what will execute if `isAlegalKey()` is true, so change `if (!isAlegalKey(c)) {` to `if (isAlegalKey(c)) {`, and what you replaced `continue` with will execute.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that the bad practice doesn't lie in the "continue" but rather in the use of the !isALegalKey construction. This is more readable/clear.

```
while (hasNotQuitted) {
    c = getch();

    if (isAlegalKey(c)) {
        if(write(fd[1], &c, 1) < 0) {
            sysCallFailureProcedure();
        }
        kill(pid, SIGUSR2);

        if (c == QUIT_KEY) {
            hasNotQuitted = false;
        }
    }
}
```